# CORS error is only occurring on auth0 login request

Tags: node.js, api, authentication, cors

I am making a simple fetch request but I keep getting a CORS error on my request for an Auth0 login.

```
fetch('http://localhost:3001/login')
.then((res) => res.json())
.then((data) => {console.log('success')})
.catch(error => {console.log(error)})}
```

The server handles this request here:

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('auth0', {
    prompt: 'login',
    scope: 'openid email profile',
    domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
    clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: process.env.AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL || 'http://localhost:3000/callback'

}), (req, res) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');
    console.log('hit')
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

I have been playing around with formatting for a while now.  I just don't see what is causing the error.

Comment: 1) it seems you are not handling the preflight request (it will be `OPTIONS` and not `GET`) - 2) it's useless to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in a request since it's a response header. - maybe fixing #2 will also fix #1 because the preflight request may no longer be necessary without that "unsafe" header. - 3) You redirect to `/` in your response but maybe the code at `/` does _not_ return CORS headers...

Comment: I have tried updating both of these things and I still get this error: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3001/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Ok so there _is_ a preflight request and you seem to _not_ handle it... Check the exact requests and responses in the network tab to understand better what is going on

Comment: I have a sockjs-node request with a 101 status and a manifest json with a 200

Comment: Note that the devtools must be open _before_ the request is sent, otherwise you won't see it.

Comment: I'm not sure what I should be looking for.  There is my failed login request.

Comment: The full list of requests is: localhost, bundle.js, 1.chunk.js, main.chunk.js, main.ded173dd8e9a8f85b45f.hot-update.js, which all respond with a 304

Answer (score -1):

So it looks like instead of making a GET request I needed to actually route my user to the desired url.  I fixed my issue by omitting the button `onClick` and wrapping things in an `<a>`

```
<a href="http://localhost:3001/login">
  <button 
    id="loginButton">
      Log In
  </button>
</a>
```